# How to manage a better way of including secondary authors of a java class as a comment?

Tags: java, spring-boot, comments

I would love to know a best practice of adding a secondary author who added or modified a java class who is other than the first author. This seems to be a better practice that provides clarity other than commits in git. Please refer to below as a reference. What I have included is the first author of the code.

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException;

/**
 * @author Lahiru_Wijesekara
 */
@ControllerAdvice
@Log4j2
public class ExceptionHandlerController {
```

Comment: The better practice would be to remote the `author` stuff entirely.

Comment: I believe that you are asking to remove it. I would kindly request you to highlight the reason behind removing the author.@luk2302

Comment: Because it serves no purpose, declared authorship implies ownership / responsibility and neither should be a thing.

Comment: An interesting response. Even I didn't think of that aspect. One of the reasons to ask the question is the organization wanted to maintain such ownership as a practice. With your response, I can think of a different direction. We are in the process of implementing a policy to maintain coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can add second author with new `@author`.
In your example:

```java
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException;

/**
 * @author Lahiru_Wijesekara
 * @author Firstname Surname
 */
@ControllerAdvice
@Log4j2
public class ExceptionHandlerController {
```

For example, InteliiJ understands this syntax and lists the authors with a decimal point. It's example from Spring `@RestController` annotation in my IDE:

[image: ![1]]

As you can see in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) authors are also given in this format.

Comment: I good one which you have highlighted. I would love to get many of your responses to confirm the answer.

Comment: Honestly, I don't suspect that there is clearly defined good practice in this regard. Like the @luk2302 said, in most cases you don't need this information. It's only for docs, noone should use this comment to identify the author of a given functionality. For this we have version control systems that have information about the author of the change.